# Adding noise to multiple images in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, edit, noise

I'm trying to add noise to multiple images in one folder using Matlab, and saving them on another folder, using the following code.

```matlab
%save the noise parameter.
noise = [0.01,0.02,0.03];

for i = 1:4

%we generate the filename (you can adapt this code)
imname = dir(fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\Amplifier',sprintf('*d%.tiff',i)));
%read the image.
im = imread(imname);

for j = 1:length(noise)

%apply the noise
J = imnoise(im,'salt & pepper',noise(j));
%save image in the right folder
imwrite(J,dir(fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\amp-matlab',sprintf('amp-matlab%d',j))));

end
end
```

I get the following error when running the code:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, `imread` expects a string and you're giving it the struct output from `dir`...

```
for i = 1:4
imstruct = dir(fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\Amplifier',sprintf('*d%.tiff',i)));
% If you know that there is only 1 file which will be returned by your
% dir command (not always a safe assumption) then you can use
% im = imread(imstruct.name);
% If you were using wildcards then there would be multiple elements in the 
% imstruct struct. Say you wanted the first one, you would use
im = imread(imstruct(1).name);
% This will work if there is only 1 item returned, so safer to use anyway

% ... other code
```

`imread` documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html

`dir` documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html

Answer (score 0):

Note: `dir` command in your code `imname = dir(...)` will return **directory list**, and `imread` in your code `im = imread(imname);` expect single file name.

You've to loop through directory items and them read one by one as shown:

```
files = dir('*.tiff');
for file = files'
    im = imread(file.name);
    % Do some stuff
end
```

Comment: Technically not correct.  It returns a **structure array**, not a list.  However, the code itself is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found few problems in your implementation.
I tried to fix the code as much as I could, when trying to follow your original logic.

Main issues:

---

- Replace `d%` with `%d`:

Original:

```
imname = dir(fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\Amplifier', sprintf('*d%.tiff',i)));
```

Corrected:

```
imname = dir(fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\Amplifier', sprintf('*%d.tiff',i)));
```

---

- `dir` command is used for list folder contents, you can't use it when writing a file.
- You may use two indexes for destination file name, because your are generating 3 destination images per one source image.
  Better approach, is using the name of the input file, and concatenating the index to it's name.

Original:

```
imwrite(J, dir(fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\amp-matlab',sprintf('amp-matlab%d',j))));
```

Corrected:

```
imwrite(J, fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\amp-matlab', sprintf('amp%d_%s', j, imname)));
```

Create output file names like:
`amp1_im1.tiff`
`amp2_im1.tiff`
`amp3_im1.tiff`
`amp1_im2.tiff`
`...`

---

The first part of my code sample, build input files for testing my implementation in my PC.
You may use it as baseline (don't forget to remove it).

I put few comments in the code regarding few more minor issues.

The code:

```
%Create input data for testing in my PC.
%Used only for verifiying my implementation is correct.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
I = imread('cameraman.tif');

for i = 1:4
    imname = ['C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\Amplifier\', sprintf('im%d.tiff', i)];
    imwrite(imresize(I, 1/i), imname); %Build images with different sizes for testing...
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%save the noise parameter.
noise = [0.01,0.02,0.03];

%Input folder:
indir = 'C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\Amplifier\';

%Following loop assumes there are exactly 4 input tiff images in the input folder.
for i = 1:4
    %Dir command: return a list of files.
    imname = dir(fullfile(indir, sprintf('*%d.tiff',i)));

    %Assume only the first image is relevant (just for example purpose).
    imname = imname(1).name;

    %Attach input folder to file name.
    full_imname = fullfile(indir, imname);

    %Read the image.
    im = imread(full_imname);

    for j = 1:length(noise)
        %apply the noise
        J = imnoise(im,'salt & pepper',noise(j));

        %save image in the right folder
        imwrite(J, fullfile('C:\Users\bluen\Pictures\AI selection\amp-matlab', sprintf('amp%d_%s', j, imname)));
    end
end
```